# databricks | enable to ship file system logs to DBFS or storage. ???`

Tags: scala, logging, log4j, databricks

I have created an init script that helps me in getting custom logs in databricks , By default log get created at local (Driver/ worker machine ) path  log/log4j-active.log but how can I enable to ship it to DBFS or storage. ???`

%sh
ls logs

*getting below output*

```
lineage.json
log4j-active.log
log4j-mylog4j-active.log
metrics.json
product.json
stderr
stdout
ttyd_logs
usage.json
```

i want to copy my log file **log4j-mylog4j-active.log** to dbfs or blob storage anything would work ..

```
   dbutils.fs.cp("logs/log4j-mylog4j-active.log", "dbfs:/cluster-logs/")
```

I am also trying filesystem copy but can't do

*FileNotFoundException: /logs/log4j-active.log*

I have also tried to create a folder and specify the path in the logging ( in cluster advance option)

but that also didn't work , i don't know why my fs logs are not getting ship to that location of dbfs.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AtXT.png]

can i get help that how can I transfer my fs log to dbfs or storage ??

thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [enable logging in your cluster configuration](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html#cluster-log-delivery-1) (unfold "Advanced options") & specify where logs should go - by default it's a `dbfs:/cluster-logs/` (and cluster ID will be appended to it), but you can specify another path.

[image]

Comment: Hi , thanks for the response , i have tried this but my this particular log  log4j-mylog4j-active.log  is not getting delivered there ..